# iOS CLLocationManager Turn On Location Services

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

In my app, if location services is turned off, it prompts the user:  Turn On Location Services to Allow "MyAPP" to Determine Your Location.

The two option buttons are Settings and Cancel.

How do I handle when the user presses cancel?

Is there any delgate method to handle the **cancel** button press ?

Comment: You cannot do anything except displaying a message like: "You need to enable location service in order to use blablabla".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might work for what you want.

First, conform to the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol in your header file.

Then there's a delegate method you can implement.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   // if the alert view that appeared has titled "Location Denied" and user pressed on cancel button (cancel button is button at index 0)
   if(alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Location Denied"] && buttonIndex == 0)
   {
       // do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// through Button name in UIAlertview you can access which Button you are pressed*

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

```
{
```

NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if([title isEqualToString:@"cancel"])

```
  {

   }
```

}